# How to dynamically change query in using CakePHP Search Plugin?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-search-plugin

Search plugin in working well but, I have to give **either** of conditions.

Example:

```
'name' => array('type' => 'like', 'encode' => true,
             'before' => false, 'after' => true,
                'wildcardAny' => '%', 'wildcardOne' => '_'),
```

Now.. When I set it to `before false` and `after true`, it searches for:
`keyword%`

I want a condition that first search for all that is `keyword%` then, if there is a space it should do `keyword-secondword%` then search for `keywordSecondword%` then `keyword%secondword%` and finally if nothing is found then `%secondkeyword` and if still not found then `%keyword%`

Now, when I try to do:

```
if(empty($this->paginate))
{ // set query and Prg->common->process  }
```

It doesn't work!

I want heavy regex matching and stuff on controller and all the database heavy lifting by Models.

I have to search on the basis of priority.

Any ideas?

Comment: For such custom scenarios use custom type "query" and manually build your query based on the input. For "if nothing is found" you would need to run pre-querys which will be very hard to do given the complexity of such requirements.

Comment: I gather what you said. But, when I loop through, it still has the same information which it's previous cycle stored. I have updated a feature request on their GitHub. Let's hope they respond. https://github.com/CakeDC/search/issues/90